# I have a problem installing auto-py-to-exe with gevent

Tags: python, python-3.x, auto-py-to-exe

**I have a problem installing auto-py-to-exe with gevent**

**I wanted to convert the program I created in Python to .EXE format but I have an error**

*It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
I was installing a python library called auto-py-to-exe. But I have a bug in build gevent. Please help me.*

````
  Using cached auto_py_to_exe-2.7.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl (75 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pyinstaller>=4.1 in c:\users\eldasdev\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from auto-py-to-exe) (4.2)
Collecting Eel==0.12.4
  Using cached Eel-0.12.4.tar.gz (15 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: future in c:\users\eldasdev\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from Eel==0.12.4->auto-py-to-exe) (0.18.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyinstaller-hooks-contrib>=2020.6 in c:\users\eldasdev\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller>=4.1->auto-py-to-exe) (2020.11)
Requirement already satisfied: pefile>=2017.8.1 in c:\users\eldasdev\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller>=4.1->auto-py-to-exe) (2019.4.18)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32-ctypes>=0.2.0 in c:\users\eldasdev\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller>=4.1->auto-py-to-exe) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\eldasdev\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller>=4.1->auto-py-to-exe) (41.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: altgraph in c:\users\eldasdev\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from pyinstaller>=4.1->auto-py-to-exe) (0.17)
Collecting bottle
  Using cached bottle-0.12.19-py3-none-any.whl (89 kB)
Collecting bottle-websocket
  Using cached bottle-websocket-0.2.9.tar.gz (2.0 kB)
Collecting gevent-websocket
  Using cached gevent_websocket-0.10.1-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
Collecting gevent
  Using cached gevent-21.1.0.tar.gz (5.9 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.12.2 in c:\users\eldasdev\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from gevent->gevent-websocket->bottle-websocket->Eel==0.12.4->auto-py-to-exe) (1.14.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\users\eldasdev\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from cffi>=1.12.2->gevent->gevent-websocket->bottle-websocket->Eel==0.12.4->auto-py-to-exe) (2.20)
Collecting greenlet<2.0,>=0.4.17
  Using cached greenlet-1.0.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (95 kB)
Collecting whichcraft
  Using cached whichcraft-0.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.2 kB)
Collecting zope.event
  Using cached zope.event-4.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.8 kB)
Collecting zope.interface
  Using cached zope.interface-5.2.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (196 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for Eel, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for bottle-websocket, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Building wheels for collected packages: gevent
  Building wheel for gevent (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\eldasdev\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\eldasdev\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\eldasdev\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpvu9yiwvw'
       cwd: C:\Users\eldasdev\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-79g7oad2\gevent_aa412080a4cb4fc5b8959272aaf5453f
  Complete output (289 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\ares.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\backdoor.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\baseserver.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\builtins.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\contextvars.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\core.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\event.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\events.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\fileobject.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\greenlet.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\hub.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\local.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\lock.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\monkey.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\os.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\pool.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\pywsgi.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\queue.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\resolver_ares.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\resolver_thread.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\select.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\selectors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\server.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\signal.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\socket.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\ssl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\subprocess.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\thread.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\threading.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\threadpool.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\time.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\timeout.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\win32util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\_abstract_linkable.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\_compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\_config.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\_fileobjectcommon.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\_fileobjectposix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\_greenlet_primitives.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\_hub_local.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\_hub_primitives.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\_ident.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\_imap.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\_interfaces.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\_monitor.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\_patcher.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\_semaphore.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\_socket2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\_socket3.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\_socketcommon.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\_ssl2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\_ssl3.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\_sslgte279.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\_tblib.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\_threading.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\_tracer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\_util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\_util_py2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\_waiter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  copying src\gevent\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\libev
  copying src\gevent\libev\corecffi.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\libev
  copying src\gevent\libev\watcher.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\libev
  copying src\gevent\libev\_corecffi_build.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\libev
  copying src\gevent\libev\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\libev
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\libuv
  copying src\gevent\libuv\loop.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\libuv
  copying src\gevent\libuv\watcher.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\libuv
  copying src\gevent\libuv\_corecffi_build.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\libuv
  copying src\gevent\libuv\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\libuv
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\resolver
  copying src\gevent\resolver\ares.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\resolver
  copying src\gevent\resolver\blocking.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\resolver
  copying src\gevent\resolver\dnspython.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\resolver
  copying src\gevent\resolver\thread.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\resolver
  copying src\gevent\resolver\_addresses.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\resolver
  copying src\gevent\resolver\_hostsfile.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\resolver
  copying src\gevent\resolver\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\resolver
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\testing
  copying src\gevent\testing\errorhandler.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\testing
  copying src\gevent\testing\exception.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\testing
  copying src\gevent\testing\flaky.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\testing
  copying src\gevent\testing\hub.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\testing
  copying src\gevent\testing\leakcheck.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\testing
  copying src\gevent\testing\modules.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\testing
  copying src\gevent\testing\monkey_test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\testing
  copying src\gevent\testing\openfiles.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\testing
  copying src\gevent\testing\params.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\testing
  copying src\gevent\testing\patched_tests_setup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\testing
  copying src\gevent\testing\resources.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\testing
  copying src\gevent\testing\six.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\testing
  copying src\gevent\testing\skipping.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\testing
  copying src\gevent\testing\sockets.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\testing
  copying src\gevent\testing\support.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\testing
  copying src\gevent\testing\switching.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\testing
  copying src\gevent\testing\sysinfo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\testing
  copying src\gevent\testing\testcase.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\testing
  copying src\gevent\testing\testrunner.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\testing
  copying src\gevent\testing\timing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\testing
  copying src\gevent\testing\travis.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\testing
  copying src\gevent\testing\util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\testing
  copying src\gevent\testing\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\testing
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\getaddrinfo_module.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\known_failures.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\lock_tests.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__all__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__api.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__api_timeout.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__ares_host_result.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__ares_timeout.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__backdoor.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__close_backend_fd.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__contextvars.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__core.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__core_async.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__core_callback.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__core_fork.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__core_loop_run.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__core_stat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__core_timer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__core_watcher.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__destroy.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__destroy_default_loop.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__doctests.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__environ.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__event.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__events.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__examples.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__example_echoserver.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__example_portforwarder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__example_udp_client.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__example_udp_server.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__example_webproxy.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__example_wsgiserver.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__example_wsgiserver_ssl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__exc_info.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__execmodules.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__fileobject.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__getaddrinfo_import.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__greenio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__greenlet.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__GreenletExit.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__greenletset.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__greenness.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__hub.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__hub_join.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__hub_join_timeout.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__import_blocking_in_greenlet.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__import_wait.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__issue112.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__issue1686.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__issue230.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__issue330.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__issue467.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__issue6.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__issue600.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__issue607.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__issue639.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__issues461_471.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__issue_728.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__iwait.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__joinall.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__local.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__lock.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__loop_callback.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__makefile_ref.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__memleak.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__monkey.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__monkey_builtins_future.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__monkey_futures_thread.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__monkey_hub_in_thread.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__monkey_logging.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__monkey_module_run.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__monkey_multiple_imports.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__monkey_queue.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__monkey_select.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__monkey_selectors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__monkey_sigchld.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__monkey_sigchld_2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__monkey_sigchld_3.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__monkey_ssl_warning.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__monkey_ssl_warning2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__monkey_ssl_warning3.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__nondefaultloop.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__order.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__os.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__pool.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__pywsgi.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__queue.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__real_greenlet.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__refcount.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__refcount_core.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__resolver_dnspython.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__select.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__selectors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__semaphore.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__server.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__server_pywsgi.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__signal.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__sleep0.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__socket.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__socketpair.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__socket_close.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__socket_dns.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__socket_dns6.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__socket_errors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__socket_ex.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__socket_send_memoryview.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__socket_ssl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__socket_timeout.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__ssl.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__subprocess.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__subprocess_interrupted.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__subprocess_poll.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__systemerror.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__thread.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__threading.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__threading_2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__threading_before_monkey.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__threading_holding_lock_while_monkey.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__threading_monkey_in_thread.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__threading_native_before_monkey.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__threading_no_monkey.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__threading_patched_local.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__threading_vs_settrace.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__threadpool.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__threadpool_executor_patched.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__timeout.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test__util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test___config.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test___ident.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test___monitor.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test___monkey_patching.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\_blocks_at_top_level.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\_imports_at_top_level.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\_imports_imports_at_top_level.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\_import_import_patch.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\_import_patch.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\_import_wait.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\__main__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\_ffi
  copying src\gevent\_ffi\callback.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\_ffi
  copying src\gevent\_ffi\loop.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\_ffi
  copying src\gevent\_ffi\watcher.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\_ffi
  copying src\gevent\_ffi\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\_ffi
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests\monkey_package
  copying src\gevent\tests\monkey_package\issue1526_no_monkey.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests\monkey_package
  copying src\gevent\tests\monkey_package\issue1526_with_monkey.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests\monkey_package
  copying src\gevent\tests\monkey_package\issue302monkey.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests\monkey_package
  copying src\gevent\tests\monkey_package\script.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests\monkey_package
  copying src\gevent\tests\monkey_package\threadpool_monkey_patches.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests\monkey_package
  copying src\gevent\tests\monkey_package\threadpool_no_monkey.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests\monkey_package
  copying src\gevent\tests\monkey_package\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests\monkey_package
  copying src\gevent\tests\monkey_package\__main__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests\monkey_package
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\testing\coveragesite
  copying src\gevent\testing\coveragesite\sitecustomize.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\testing\coveragesite
  copying src\gevent\tests\2_7_keycert.pem -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\badcert.pem -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\badkey.pem -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\https_svn_python_org_root.pem -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\keycert.pem -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\nullcert.pem -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\sha256.pem -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\wrongcert.pem -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\server.crt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test_server.crt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\hosts_file.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\tests_that_dont_do_leakchecks.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\tests_that_dont_monkeypatch.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\tests_that_dont_use_resolver.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\server.key -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  copying src\gevent\tests\test_server.key -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\gevent\tests
  running build_ext
  generating cffi module 'build\\temp.win-amd64-3.9\\Release\\gevent.libuv._corecffi.c'
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
  building 'gevent.libev.corecext' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for gevent
Failed to build gevent
ERROR: Could not build wheels for gevent which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly```
````

Answer (score 0):

you seem have one of the same trouble i have before. Fist install Microsofth c++,
after uninstall gevent, greenlet, Eel, pipwin, pypiwin32, pywin32, pyinstaller and auto-py-to-exe. After that, alway's in the terminal, pip install wheel, pip install -U setuptools, and all the package you have uninstaled, pywin32, pypiwin32, piwin, greenlet, gevent, Eel, pyinstaller and auto-py-to-exe. In this order for the two last one. That work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the C++ Build Tools. You can download them [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/). When they've downloaded, restart your PC and try installing again :)